# JS: error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, https, nativescript, okhttp

I follow this step to work with plugin `nativescripts-https`:

1: Install: `tns plugin add nativescript-https`

2:  Add in app.grandle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
  }
```

3: Add in tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2016"
        ],
```

4: Add in component.ts

```
  gethttps(){
    Https.disableSSLPinning();
    Https.request({
        url: 'https://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4433/json',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        },
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Https.request response', response)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Https.request error', error)
    })
  }
```

5: Add in component.html

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="message" (tap)="gethttps()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

When I click the button to show this error in console.

> JS: nativescript-https > Disabled SSL pinning
>   JS: error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

Please, any idea how to solve this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: have you tried with the http methods you get with angular by default? they work out the box and dont require any extra plugins to work

Comment: Yes I try but not function.

Comment: what isnt a function? they are functions and they work perfectly?

Comment: I need to use https protocol.not http protocol. Can you suggest how to solution this error please?

Comment: thats something you change/decide in the server code, not the app

Comment: How to call from app please? Can you show any example please?

Comment: you need to `import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";` in the app.module and then also a service file

Comment: I also want to avoid the certificate. Yes I import HttpModule

Comment: avoid the certificate how? you cant connect to a https api _and_ avoid the certificate

Comment: For this I want to use `nativescripts-https`

Comment: that plugin wont let you avoid the certificate, that would defeat the point of how https works

Comment: you think it is impossible to avoid the certificate?

Comment: why do you want to avoid it? theyre used for a reason

Comment: I want to allow invalid certificate. In plugin is possible, look https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https in Options `allowInvalidCertificates?: boolean`

Comment: but the app doesnt choose which certificate to use on the server, to my knowledge its to load a cert onto the phone to trick the server into thinking its something else, why not just correct your cert so it isnt invalid?